# Pygame Sprites Dissapearing

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, sprite

On my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43454651/pygame-sprite-movement-causes-layers) I had trouble with sprites. So I decided to use clear method before drawing them. It seemed to have worked but when the sprites got to the bottom of the screen, which is when they are supposed to back to top, they dissapeared. Only 2 of 9 remained.

**Before they reached the bottom.**
[image]


**After they reached the bottom and reseted to top.**
[image]

## Main file

```
#!/usr/bin/python
VERSION = "0.1"
import os, sys, raindrop
from os import path

try:
    import pygame
    from pygame.locals import *
except ImportError, err:
    print 'Could not load module %s' % (err)
    sys.exit(2)

# main variables
WIDTH, HEIGHT, FPS = 300, 300, 30


# initialize game
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Rain and Rain")

# background
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background = background.convert()
background.fill((40,44,52))

# blitting
screen.blit(background,(0,0))
pygame.display.flip()

# clock for FPS settings
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


def main():
    raindrops = pygame.sprite.Group()

    # a function to create new drops
    def newDrop():
        nd = raindrop.Raindrop()
        raindrops.add(nd)

    # creating 10 rain drops
    for x in range(0,9): newDrop()

    # variable for main loop
    running = True

    # event loop
    while running:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False


        screen.blit(background,(100,100))
        raindrops.clear(screen,background)
        raindrops.update()
        raindrops.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

## raindrop.py ( class )

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from os import path
from random import randint
from rain import HEIGHT

img_dir = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'img')

class Raindrop(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.width = randint(32, 64)
        self.height = self.width + 33
        self.image = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, "raindrop.png")).convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (self.width, self.height))
        self.speedy = 5 #randint(1, 8)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = randint(0, 290)
        self.rect.y = -self.height

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.y == HEIGHT:
            self.rect.y = -self.height
            self.rect.x = randint(0, 290)
```

Comment: Don't include all code; create a [mcve] instead. It'll make the question more beneficial for other people as it becomes easier to read, understand, test/verify and it'll also make it easier for the people who are trying to figure out the problem.

Comment: Will be thinking about that for the next time xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if self.rect.y == HEIGHT:
```

Problem is some rain drops will go exceed `HEIGHT`, because `speedy` is a random number in range [1,8], so multiple of `speedy` might not be divisible by `2*HEIGHT`. For example `speedy = 7`, `rect.y` goes from -HEIGHT = -300 to -293, -286, ..., 295, then to 302 which is greater than 300, so the `==` check will never be true, and the rain drop goes down forever.

A simple change to `>=` will solve the problem:

```
if self.rect.y >= HEIGHT:
```